# ResultSetMetaData to Filewriter/CSV issue JAVA

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

This code prints 4 data headers and data below in my CSV file correctly in columns A-D
However, in columns E-H there is a Random set of data.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            out.print(name);
            if (i != columnCount + 1) {
                out.print(",");
                System.out.print(i);

            }
        }

        while (result.next()) {
            out.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", result.getString(1),
                    result.getString(2), result.getString(3),
                    result.getString(4)));


        }
        result.close();
        statement.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Post a snipet. CSV is a text file format, so you can post a couple of bad lines and what you expect to see. I'm suggesting that because there does not appear to be anything terribly wrong with the code.

Comment: Sorry guys, the issue is the "8243, 9 , 110, -0.05" showing up as headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no newline character being written after the column names have been written, resulting in the first row of data appearing as column headers. Write a newline character after the `for` loop that writes the column names.

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill do that just now :D sorry for making a right mess of the question swell haha